# USB 3.0 External Drive with LUKS encoding will not be mounted

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, usb-drive, fdisk

I recently reformatted a 3TB Sandisk usb 3.0 external hard drive with LUKS using the Disks application according to this [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage). The drive worked after the encryption, but since I restarted my computer, the drive will not mount. I can see it listed when I run `lsusb`, but not in `fdisk`. Without it mounting, I cannot even see it in Disks or gParted to reformat and remove the encryption.

Here is the output of the lsusb (see Bus 009 Device 004):

```
jay@JaysDesktop:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 045e:0291 Microsoft Corp. Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 004: ID 0bc2:2322 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
```

And the dmesg:

```
jay@JaysDesktop:~$ dmesg | tail
[  370.868956] usb 9-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  370.868960] usb 9-1: SerialNumber: NA83LRMY
[ 1712.255840]  sda: sda1 sda2
[ 2449.676250] usb 9-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 2453.636771] usb 9-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2453.657206] usb 9-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322
[ 2453.657213] usb 9-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 2453.657218] usb 9-1: Product: Expansion
[ 2453.657222] usb 9-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 2453.657225] usb 9-1: SerialNumber: NA83LRMY
```

And the /var/log/syslog output:

```
jay@JaysDesktop:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Dec 21 00:04:11 JaysDesktop kernel: [ 2449.676250] usb 9-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Dec 21 00:04:15 JaysDesktop kernel: [ 2453.636771] usb 9-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Dec 21 00:04:15 JaysDesktop kernel: [ 2453.657206] usb 9-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322
Dec 21 00:04:15 JaysDesktop kernel: [ 2453.657213] usb 9-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Dec 21 00:04:15 JaysDesktop kernel: [ 2453.657218] usb 9-1: Product: Expansion
Dec 21 00:04:15 JaysDesktop kernel: [ 2453.657222] usb 9-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
Dec 21 00:04:15 JaysDesktop kernel: [ 2453.657225] usb 9-1: SerialNumber: NA83LRMY
Dec 21 00:04:15 JaysDesktop mtp-probe: checking bus 9, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb9/9-1"
Dec 21 00:04:15 JaysDesktop mtp-probe: bus: 9, device: 4 was not an MTP device
```

I have tried the `modprobe usb_storage` solution, and it did not work for me, as well as turning off/on the computer with the drive in/out.

This is the second drive this has happened on. The first one experienced the exact same issue, I assumed a hardware failure and returned it for this one. Since it happened the same way on two brand new external drives in a row, I am almost certain it is not a mechanical failure.

Please if you have any suggestions, I would be so thankful. I thought setting an encrypted backup drive would be easy...

Comment: Okay, so I was able to see and reformat the drive to NTFS in Windows. However, the drive still does not load in Ubuntu. The dmesg now stops at the drive SerialNumber. Looking at dmesg and comparing a successful usb drive mount vs what my current drive is doing, it looks like usb-storage is not detecting it as mass storage device.

Is there any reason that usb-storage wouldn't detect this drive, but would recognize others?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved this issue, and figured I would post back for anyone who happens to find this years from now.

Initially, I was unable to read the LUKS encrypted disk for some unknown reason. While investigating this issue I stupidly added the line:

```
blacklist uas
```

to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` without knowing what it meant after seeing it recommended online.

Once I plugged into a Windows machine and reformatted the drive to NTFS, my original computer still couldn't load the drive, although my other Linux machine could. I realized that it must be a configuration error (not an issue with the drive). After lots of searching, I found that there was no driver being assigned to the USB drive, which then led me down a deep rabbit hole, in which someone luckily mentioned the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file in passing, and I thought the file location looked familiar. Once I removed that line, the drive worked perfectly again.

I will be keeping it as an NTFS drive, because there is now support to password-protect backups, and that's all I really wanted in the first place.